# Dynamic ChartJS Chart Updated in Rails with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using Rails 5 and the latest ChartJS library (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/).

What I want to accomplish is to GET the latest 20 items from the SensorReading model and update the Chart with setInterval and AJAX.

I've built the AJAX call and I've loaded the Chart but I fail in two things.

First of of all I get a Syntax Error when reading data from Rails:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'

var labels = [&quot;2016-07-03 10:33:49 +0300&quot;, &quot;2016-07-03 10:3
```

No matter what I tried, they keep to appear with `&quot;` instead of quotes.

Secondly I am unable to update the Chart, as I need a handler available for the Chart itself to call .update() on it.

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<div class="ui divider"></div>

<div class="ui padded grid">
  <div class="four wide column">
    <div class="ui statistic">
      <div class="value">
        <%= @temperature %>.C
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        TEMPERATURE
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="ui statistic">
      <div class="value">
        <%= @humidity %>%
      </div>
      <div class="label">
        HUMIDITY
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="twelve wide column">
    <div class="ui segment">
      <div class="line-chart" style="max-height: 400px; display:block;">
        <canvas id="updating-chart"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>


<script>
var labels = <%= @sensor_readings.map(&:created_at) %>;

var canvas = document.getElementById('updating-chart'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    startingData = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
          {
              fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: <%= @sensor_readings.map(&:temperature) %>
          },
          {
              fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: <%= @sensor_readings.map(&:humidity) %>
          }
      ]
    },
    latestLabel = startingData.labels[6];

// Reduce the animation steps for demo clarity.
var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx , {
    type: "line",
    data: startingData,
    animationSteps: 15
});

setInterval(function(){
  // Add two random numbers for each dataset
  //myLiveChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 50; // Would update the first dataset's value of 'March' to be 50
  myLiveChart.update(); // Calling update now animates the position of March from 90 to 50.
}, 5000);

</script>
```

**dashboard.js**

```
var ready = function(){

  setInterval(refreshSensorReadings, 3000);

  function refreshSensorReadings(){
    console.log("--> Called");
    $.rails.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'script',
      url: "/sensor_readings_chart_data.js",
      success: function(result){
        //$('.line-chart').html(result);
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
  };


};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
```

**route**

```
get 'sensor_readings_chart_data', to: 'sensor_readings#chart_data'
```

**sensor_readings_controller.rb**

```
def chart_data
    @sensor_readings = SensorReading.last(20)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
      format.js  
    end
  end
```

Any advice will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) method:

> Marks a string as trusted safe. It will be inserted into HTML with no
>   additional escaping performed. It is your responsibilty to ensure that
>   the string contains no malicious content. This method is equivalent to
>   the `raw` helper in views. It is recommended that you use `sanitize`
>   instead of this method. **It should never be called on user input**.

```
 datasets: [
      {
          fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
          data: <%= @sensor_readings.map(&:temperature).html_safe %>
      },
      {
          fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
          data: <%= @sensor_readings.map(&:humidity).html_safe %>
      }
  ]
```

Comment: This is not possible because it's an array. "undefined method `html_safe' for #<Array:0x00000008adf6a8>".

Comment: @ChrisV. ok, try this `@sensor_readings.map { |i| i.humidity.html_safe }` and `@sensor_readings.map { |i| i.temperature.html_safe }`

Comment: Every variable has its type so it's not possible again. `humidity` is a decimal so html_safe cannot be called. Only chance is If `humidity.to_s.html_safe` where I get the same msg: `var labels = [&quot;2016-07-03 10:33:49 +0300&quot;, &quot;2016-07-03 10:3. `

Comment: _humidity is a decimal_ this is not a decimal `2016-07-03 10:33:49 +0300`, anyway you can try use `raw(@sensor_readings.map(&:temperature))` helper.

Comment: This was about the created_at datetime but even with raw it doesn't work.

Comment: But `created_at datetime` is not a decimal, here is another hack `data: <%= raw @sensor_readings.map(&:humidity).to_json %>;`

Comment: What you mean by _why?_ The `raw` method outputs without escaping a string.